# No automatic column names with shift in a data.table - give.names = TRUE

Tags: r, data.table

Creating a lagged variable inside a data.table with `shift` should according to the documentation of shift create a column name based on the `type` and `n` options. That's apparently not working in my case and I would like to know why and how I can achieve that without resorting to the usage of variables to name the columns.

```
dt.quarter.test <- structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L)
               , City = c("New York","New York","New York","New York","Philadelphia","Philadelphia","Philadelphia","Philadelphia")
               , Quarter = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)
               , Data.Year.to.Date = c(162, 405, 610, 938, 331, 1467, 1981, 2501)
               )
          , .Names = c("Year", "City", "Quarter", "Data.Year.to.Date"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))

dt.quarter.test[, .(Quarter, Data.Year.to.Date, shift(Data.Year.to.Date, n = 1L, type = "lag", fill = NA, give.names = TRUE)), by = list(City)]
```

Edit: 
Resulting data.table in my case, also making sure using shift from the data.table 1.9.6 package, by using `data.table::shift`.

```
           City Quarter Data.Year.to.Date   V3
1:     New York       1               162   NA
2:     New York       2               405  162
3:     New York       3               610  405
4:     New York       4               938  610
5: Philadelphia       1               331   NA
6: Philadelphia       2              1467  331
7: Philadelphia       3              1981 1467
8: Philadelphia       4              2501 1981
```

Comment: Adjusted the question to show the results also.

Comment: Guess that the `give.names=TRUE` argument makes sense only if `x` is a `data.frame`, `data.table` or a `list`, not if it is a regular `vector`.

Comment: @nicola: why not? In my opinion, this is kind of a prime example for giving this column a name based on the input of the shift function.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that (I guess) the argument has been thought to give names to the elements of a list, not to give name to an object. If you pass a `list` to `shift`, it can change the names of the *elements* of the list. If you just pass a vector (as you are doing in your line), `shift` can change the names of the elements of the vector, but this isn't much useful. Try for instance `x<-1:10` then `shift(x,give.names=TRUE)` and `shift(list(x=x),give.names=TRUE)` and see the difference.

Comment: I've just found, that in the examples, given in the documentation, they explicitly use `paste` to create the column names for the shifted variables :-)

Comment: This seems to be a desired behaviour given that _[...] it returns an unnamed list by default as assigning names for each group over and over can be quite time consuming with many groups._

Comment: @m-dz but this is not true, when `give.names = TRUE`, since then it should set names automatically.

Comment: @hannes101 Indeed, so you should do the same in your example. If you pass a `data.table` to `shift` (like `.SD`), then the names are set automatically. If you pass a single column (which isn't a list), names are not set, whether the value of `give.names`.

Comment: After a bit of debugging: the last step of the `shift` function: `setattr(ans, "names", do.call("paste", c(CJ(nx, type, n, sorted = FALSE), sep = "_")))` is indeed creating the expected name: `Data.Year.to.Date_lag_1`, unfortunately only for the first element of the numeric vector `ans`: (pre-naming) `num [1:4] NA 162 405 610`, (post-naming) `Named num [1:4] NA 162 405 610 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] Data.Year.to.Date_lag_1" NA NA NA`. This seems to be a bug.

Comment: @m-dz Don't agree it's a bug. `shift` can be used also outside of a `data.table` and with a non-list argument. What should  `shift(1:10,1,give.names=TRUE)` return in your opinion?

Comment: @nicola, definitely not the named vector with only first element having a name, as it does now: `Named int [1:10] NA 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "V1_lag_1" NA NA NA ...`. Maybe a `list('V1_lag_1' = shift(1:10,1))`?

Comment: @hannes101, found a better one: `by_cols <- 'City';
cbind(
  dt.quarter.test,
  dt.quarter.test[
    ,
    shift(.SD, n = 1L, type = "lag", fill = NA, give.names = TRUE),
    .SDcols = 'Data.Year.to.Date',
    by = by_cols][, .SD, .SDcols = !by_cols]
)`

Comment: @hannes101 in your example you forgot `give.names=TRUE`... don't getting how `shift` could do "more" inside a `data.table`.

Comment: @m-dz I agree that the result in that case could be different (maybe `give.names` shouldn't have any effect on non-lists), but, in any case, the desired result cannot ever be what the OP wanted (which is basically a name change of the object argument).

Comment: @nicola, yeah forgot that and you're right. What I mean is that in this case it knows the name of the column vector, so it should in my opinion be able to modify it and even if it does not have a name as in your example. It could still modify the "name" of the vector indicating the transformation applied.

Comment: @nicola, isn't the `give.names` meant to do exactly that, force the naming when you really want it and know what you are doing? Hence the defaul `FALSE`.

Comment: Maybe my English is not good enough and I'm not making myself clear. `shift` sometimes returns a `list` and sometimes it doesn't. When it does, it does assign names to the output list if `give.names` is set to `TRUE`. If it doesn't return a list, how could it change the name of the object? It's like if you had a function `foo` that calling `foo(x)` has the effect of changing the name `x` in something else. I agree that `shift` could return a list always. But it doesn't and it's documented, so not a bug.

Comment: I see what you mean, maybe I should have called it a _not the expected (by me) behaviour_. My point is, the `data.table::shift` is not changing the `x` when it is called, it is simply returning another object, the `ans`, see line 3 here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/shift.R and `tracemem` just to be sure: `my_vec <- 1:10;
tracemem(my_vec);
data.table::shift(my_vec,1,give.names=TRUE);
tracemem(my_vec)`, so I see no problems in changing vectors to a named list. Maybe we should move the further discussion to the chat?

Comment: The doc says why sometimes it's convenient to have a vector (`newcol:=colA+shift(colB)` inside a `data.table`: you couldn't sum them if `shift` returns a `list`). I'd say that the most that can be done is to add another argument `drop=TRUE` which covers this case and allows to return a list when needed.

Comment: @nicola, completely agree, missed that line in the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot fit this into a comment, plus this seems to be a (rather ugly, but) solution:

```
library(data.table)

dt.quarter.test <- structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L)
                                  , City = c("New York","New York","New York","New York","Philadelphia","Philadelphia","Philadelphia","Philadelphia")
                                  , Quarter = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)
                                  , Data.Year.to.Date = c(162, 405, 610, 938, 331, 1467, 1981, 2501)
)
, .Names = c("Year", "City", "Quarter", "Data.Year.to.Date"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))

by_cols <- 'City'
shift_cols <- 'Data.Year.to.Date'  # or e.g. c('Data.Year.to.Date','Quarter')
cbind(
  dt.quarter.test,
  dt.quarter.test[
    ,
    shift(.SD, n = 1L, type = "lag", fill = NA, give.names = TRUE),
    .SDcols = shift_cols,
    by = by_cols][, .SD, .SDcols = !by_cols]
)
```

Result:

```
   Year         City Quarter Data.Year.to.Date Data.Year.to.Date_lag_1
1: 2000     New York       1               162                      NA
2: 2000     New York       2               405                     162
3: 2000     New York       3               610                     405
4: 2000     New York       4               938                     610
5: 2001 Philadelphia       1               331                      NA
6: 2001 Philadelphia       2              1467                     331
7: 2001 Philadelphia       3              1981                    1467
8: 2001 Philadelphia       4              2501                    1981
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah it's a solution, but I thought it could be accomplished easier.

Comment: @hannes101, you would need to adjust the function's code, might be worth trying to raise an issue on `data.table` github page.

Comment: did just that now. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1971